# Index on Left join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm new to Mysql and im trying to do a left join between 2 tables but it takes ages to do it.

I think I might me missing something in my noob query. I don't know how indexes work very well but I think there have to be indexes for every join column.

Firstly, I create the index for the joinning columns (MANDT, KUNNR, POSNR, MODAT), as well as the columns that are going to be joined to the other table.

```
CREATE INDEX aux03_financiero_idx ON aux03_financiero (ESTAD, TIPPTO, MANDT,  KUNNR, POSNR, MODAT, DPTOCODE, SW_RRHH);
```

I also create the index on the table that I want to have all the columns.

```
CREATE INDEX aux71_idx ON aux71 (MANDT,KUNNR, POSNR, MODAT);
```

After creating the indexes on the joinning columns I run the query, but never ends.

Each table contain aprox. 3M rows, so it's not a big table. Mysql should be able to do this with out any probs. There arent't any foreign keys or primary keys created, but indexes should do it I think.

```
CREATE TABLE FINANCIERO71 as select 
        A.MANDT,
        A.KUNNR,
        A.MODAT,
        A.POSNR,
        A.MODAT_R,
        A.MOV_TYPE,
        B.ESTAD,
        A.ORIG as hotel_ori,
        A.DESt as hotel_des,
        case when A.ORIG!='' then substring(A.ORIG,1,2)
            else substring(B.DPTOCODE,1,2) end as pais_origen,
        B.TIPPTO,
        B.DPTOCODE,
        B.SW_RRHH,
        A.PUNTOS,
        B.PUNTOS2,
        A.CANC,
        A.DATUM,
        A.UZEIT,
        A.NUMMOV,
        A.NUMMOV_ORIG,
        A.FECHA_CANC, 
        A.FECHA_CADUC,
        A.modat_mes,
        A.modat_ano,
        A.prombasic,
        substring(A.FECHA_CADUC,1,6) as modat_caduc_mes,
        substring(A.FECHA_CANC,1,6) as modat_cancel_mes,
        A.MarcaH
From aux71 as A
left join aux03_financiero as B
    on A.MANDT = B.MANDT 
    AND A.KUNNR = B.KUNNR
    AND A.MODAT = B.MODAT 
    AND A.POSNR = B.POSNR;
```

Would really appreciate your help. If you need any more info please just tell me.

Comment: You shouldn't have to create an index for all the joined columns, especially because every insert, update or delete you might have on that table will require an update of the index too. You should have a primary key on your table, instead, unless it is a very particular case. Also, a primary key is itself an index.

Comment: Second question: why are you creating a table instead of using a select? If you need to store the results of your join, I would use a view, rather than creating a table.

Comment: Could it be storing the data in a table the reason why this query is taking so long?

Comment: It might be, and in any case the `create` statement will never return a result, because there is no result to return. It's the `select` statement that does that.

Answer (score 2):

The index that you want is:

```
CREATE INDEX aux03_financiero_idx ON aux03_financiero (MANDT, KUNNR, MODAT, POSNR);
```

These are the columns used for joining and they need to be the first columns in the index.  You can add additional columns as well *after* these columns, but this should significantly improve your performance.

Comment: No need the index in the aux71 table? `CREATE INDEX aux71_idx ON aux71 (MANDT,KUNNR, POSNR, MODAT);`

Comment: @Suanbit Yes having the index on both tables might be useful to have more room for optimization. Note: Order of columns in the index is important.

Comment: @Suanbit . . . That index doesn't really help.  The `LEFT JOIN` means that all rows from the first table need to be in the result set.  There is little to no advantage to reading the values from an index rather than directly from the table.